# How to type '<' in latex

Tags: latex

I would like to type less than the symbol '<' in latex. Does anybody know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible ways of doing it. Use it depending on your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Plain text: \textless{}

Equation: \(<\) % Or $<$

\end{document}
```